# How to import module from one python file to another python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I am confused with importing in python  and I am using two python files.

**re1.py:**

```
import datetime

import re2
```

**re2.py:**

```
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

When I run the re1.py file, it gave the error,

```
print datetime.datetime.now()
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

What is the best way to solve this error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `import datetime` in `re1.py`, you import it in the scope of only the `re1.py` file, and not in `re2.py`. In other words, if you import something in one module, it won't cross over onto the other.

To fix this, you must `import datetime` in `re2.py` (and you don't necessarily need it in `re1.py`)

Comment: Thanks for reply. datetime is necessary for two files. How to reuse the import modules.

Comment: @codeimplementer: The answer is right there.  You have to import it in each file where you want to use it.

Comment: @codeimplementer I don't know what you mean by re-use, but you can keep the import statement in both files

Comment: I mean one file contains all modules and another file import that file. sorry my English is poor.

Comment: @codeimplementer Unless you want to do `re2.datetime`, and the same for every other module, it's better to just import them all in `re1.py`

Answer (score 0):

your code should be:
re1.py:

```
import datetime  
import re2
```

re2.py:

```
import datetime  
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

`import re2` **doesn't means** simply replace the statement with another file:

```
import datetime  
# re2.py  
import datetime  
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

you have to make sure all the modules you import are working.